# Problema com envio de smtp Swift_Message com Symfony2

Tags: php, smtp, swiftmailer

Olá, estou com um problema quando uso o SMTP com Swift_Message.

Coloco as informações certinho e o email chega. P problema é que chega um email tanto para o "From" como para o "To". Isso é normal ou tenho que configurar alguma coisa para que isso não aconteça?

vou colocar o código feito com Symfony2 que, apesar de ser um framework, dá pra entender o que esta sendo feito.

```
$transport = \Swift_SmtpTransport::newInstance($host, $port, $security)
    ->setUsername($login)
    ->setPassword($senha)
    ->setAuthMode('login');

    $mailer = \Swift_Mailer::newInstance($transport);

    $message = \Swift_Message::newInstance()
        ->setSubject($titulo)
        ->setFrom($from)
        ->setTo($para)
        ->setBody(
            $conteudo,
            'text/html'
        );

    $mailer->send($message);
```

Comment: Existe alguma configuração adicional que você está fazendo no Swiftmailer além do código acima?

Comment: Infelizmente não, eu apenas chamo esses objetos e seto os seus valores, também ache que poderia ser uma outra configuração em alguma outra parte da aplicação, mas já verifiquei e não tem.

Comment: Você sabe se existe algo configurado no servidor de saída de emails para receber uma cópia de todo e-mail enviado? Estou tentando achar algo na documentação no Swiftmailer mas não encontro nenhum problema similar ao seu.

Comment: Bem eu estou usando a DigitalOcean, não configurei servidor de email, estou setando os dados da minha conta do google, sera que a google envia o email por segurança?

Comment: Complemente a pergunta com os cabeçalhos do email recebido (abra o email recebido, vá no menu de opções e, em seguida, vá em "show original").